# On emulator and device StatusBar is treated differently

Tags: android, angular, mobile, nativescript, statusbar

I made simple tab navigation with content inside. (tested even without navigation just with button in app.compnent.tns.html) and on Android emulator button is hidden under StatusBar however on actual device it is not. I am sure i do not have any global styles applied. Can somebody advice why and what should I do to make it working simmilar?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to share your code if you need any help, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try **`android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`** in xml root layout, 
or **`<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>`** in style.xml

Answer (score 1):

It was due different version of Android (9 and 10) on device and emulator. I solved this by following this: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2110#issuecomment-576570728